# Solar Panel Voltage vs. Consumer Solar Generator

Tags: voltage, solar-cell, generator, panel

I have a 235 W solar panel that I wish to take with me on camping trips. I’m looking at getting a Goal Zero “solar generator” product to store the energy from the panel, specifically the lithium-ion versions. The battery (Yeti 1000 and Yeti 1400) is rated on the spec sheet as being able to take input of 12-22 V. The Voc of the panel is listed as 37.06 V.

Does the charge controller in the battery allow me to connect higher voltage panels and automatically lower it to match, or are these products incompatible? If so, what will the compromises be?

Assuming I want to use the battery, and want a 200+ W portable panel(s), what are my options? I just want the biggest solar panel(s) that I can fit on the roof of my car.

Thanks and sorry if this question isn’t in the scope of this section of StackExchange. I did search other questions.

Edit: links to products.

Panel (235):
http://www.suniva.com/documents/MVP60Cell_022912.pdf

Battery:
https://www.goalzero.com/shop/power-stations/goal-zero-yeti-1000-lithium-portable-power-station/

Comment: That's not camping... though if you're heading up the West Highland Way with a 235W solar panel on your backpack ... respect. In any case, some links to datasheets would probably help getting answers.

Comment: *The battery (Yeti 1000 and Yeti 1400) is rated on the spec sheet as being able to take input of **12-22 V**. The Voc of the panel is listed as **37.06 V** *. Last time I did some comparisons, 37 was larger than 22. I think it still is.

Comment: Edited to add links.